# calling api added as web reference with wsSecurity and WS-Addressing

Tags: wcf, ws-security, ws-addressing

I have to consume client API with WsSecurity(WSS) and WS-Addressing(WSA). while i am  consuming API in my app.config endpoint configured like bellow. 
i have added it as web reference.

```
<applicationSettings>
<WCFDemoforVEDA.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="WCFDemoforVEDA_VEDAServiceReference_idmatrix"
    serializeAs="String">
    <value>https://vedaxml.com/sys2/idmatrix-v4</value>
  </setting>
</WCFDemoforVEDA.Properties.Settings>
```

can you help me out how we can pass there username and password while calling api.